# How to get the value of a key chrome.storage.sync.get chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I would like to get the key value chrome.storage.sync.get.
Example: Setting the storage;

```
var domain = url.hostname + ' (' + type + ')';
                  var save = {};
      save[domain] = response;    
chrome.storage.sync.set(save,function() {
    // Notify that we saved.
            chrome.storage.sync.get(save, function (reee) {
    console.log(reee);
});
});
```

It sets this:

```
stackoverflow.com (type): "{\n    \"se:fkey\": \"8b52d88db2cc534208b006788551e0e43f25f678f8ff9c2cdcd4e8497143cbdf,1616780921\"\n}"
```

Then I retrieve it with this:

```
chrome.storage.sync.get(save, function (reee) {
    console.log(reee);
});
```

And it responds with this:

```
stackoverflow.com (type): "{\n    \"se:fkey\": \"8b52d88db2cc534208b006788551e0e43f25f678f8ff9c2cdcd4e8497143cbdf,1616780921\"\n}"
```

How  can I set a variable to this: "{\n    "se:fkey": "8b52d88db2cc534208b006788551e0e43f25f678f8ff9c2cdcd4e8497143cbdf,1616780921"\n}" after retrieving it.

Ask me if you need more explanation.

Comment: `var foo = reee['stackoverflow.com (type)']`

Comment: Yes!!!! That fixed it thank you! So much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wOxxOm Fixed It!!!!!!!!!!!
He said:

```
var foo = reee['stackoverflow.com (type)']
```

foo is the variable for: "{\n "se:fkey": "8b52d88db2cc534208b006788551e0e43f25f678f8ff9c2cdcd4e8497143cbdf,1616780921"\n}"